# Calling a variable amount of asynchronous functions that are dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to paginate through a website, where in order to request the next page, the information on the current page is required.

```
function paginateSite(numPages, cb) {
    var stringToGetToNextPage = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        (function(i, stringToGetToNextPage) {
            request({
                url: 'http://website.com',
                qs: {
                    nextPage: stringToGetToNextPage
                }
            }, 
            function(err, res, body) {
                body_json = JSON.parse(body)
                console.log(body_json.stringToGetToNextPage)
            })
        })(i, stringToGetToNextPage)
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no way for me to set stringToGetToNextPage outside of the anonymous function. I have looked through the async library documentation but couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

Has anybody ran into this problem? It seems like this is a case where the async paradigm doesn't have a clean solution.

EDIT: QUESTION #2, is there conceivably a way to do this without recursion? Recursion is fine for small examples, but now I have a stackoverflow case that can kill the program without warning (and eats up memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is the way to do this.

First, factor out a function to retrieve a single page:

```
function requestPage(stringToGetToNextPage, callback) {
    request({
        url: 'http://website.com',
        qs: {
            nextPage: stringToGetToNextPage
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) { callback(err); }
        else { callback(null, JSON.parse(body)); }
    });
}
```

Then, make a function that can recursively call itself to get each successive page:

```
function requestAllPages(stringToGetToNextPage, callback) {
    requestPage(stringToGetToNextPage, function (err, page) {
        if (err) { callback(err); }
        else if (page && page.stringToGetToNextPage) {
            requestAllPages(page.stringToGetToNextPage, callback);
        }
        else { callback(); }
    });
}
```

Then kick it all off:

```
requestAllPages(null, function () {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

---

**Edit** If you really do want to paginate a specific number of pages rather than going to the end, you can accomplish that with a small modification to `requestAllPages`:

```
function requestPages(numPages, stringToGetToNextPage, callback) {
    if (numPages <= 0) { callback(); return; }

    requestPage(stringToGetToNextPage, function (err, page) {
        if (err) { callback(err); }
        else if (page && page.stringToGetToNextPage) {
            requestPages(numPages - 1, page.stringToGetToNextPage, callback);
        }
        else { callback(); }
    });
}

requestPages(20, null, function () {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without recursion? (see edit)

Comment: @JacksonDarrow I can't think of a way to do this without recursion, but your concern about a stack overflow and excessive memory usage are unfounded. Since the calls are asynchronous, they will not be sharing the same stack, and the way my code is written, there should be at most one call of each respective function in memory at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Write a recursive function.

```
function get_page(next_page_number, last_page_number, string_needed, callback) {

    request(
        {
            url: 'http://website.com',
            qs: {
                nextPage: string_needed
            }
        }, 
        function(err, res, body) {
            // NB: Bad variable name. `body` is JSON. `body_json` won't be.
            var body_json = JSON.parse(body);

            if (next_page_number == last_page_number) {
                callback(body_json);
            } else {
                get_page(
                    next_page_number + 1, 
                    last_page_number,
                    body_json.stringToGetToNextPage,
                    callback
                );
            }
        }
    );

}

get_page(1, 27, "", function (body_json) { console.log(body_json); });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without recursion? (see edit)